# Visualforce and trigger

Tags: visualforce, trigger

When I save a record from a visualforce the salesforce also triggers the trigger? Until I know the trigger is triggered only when a record is saved from a default page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Triggers almost always execute. This includes actions in a Visualforce page, a Lightning component, an API call, or the standard user interface. There are some rare exceptions, but these are usually bugs or documented. For example, changing a picklist value in the Setup menu will modify many records, but triggers do not fire. You'd want to check the documentation if you're experiencing a situation where a trigger does not fire.

Comment: Thank u sfdfox!